# Malloc, calloc, realloc and free make the threads wait?

Tags: c, multithreading

If I invoke the same method in parallel in two or more threads, they will make the threads wait (unable to continue execution until the other thread finishes using it), like a mutex?

I want to know that because I invoke some mallocs and callocs in a cycle executed by multiple threads, multiple times for each thread.

In little programs for college assignments, that functions never caused race conditions, neither bad results not problems reported by tsan sanitizer, but I want to know if only one thread can execute they at the same time and if this make the thread to stop executing instructions until is allowed to use malloc for example.

Comment: Yes. They are thread-safe, and therefore at least key parts of them can only be executed by one thread at a time.

Comment: So, the thread cannot continue executing other instructions meanwhile ?

Comment: When a thread gets to a malloc/calloc while another is currently executing a malloc/calloc it will wait for the other one to finish calling malloc/calloc.  It is just the malloc/calloc functions that are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Whether threads hinder each other depends on which `malloc` implementation is being used by your compiler/standard library implementation. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) for a list of different `malloc` implementations. Some implementations of `malloc` use a per-thread allocator for small allocations, so that a lock is not required. That way, the threads do not hinder each other. No matter which implementation is being used, you can be sure that a race condition will not occur, as this issue will be handled internally by the allocator.

Comment: `malloc()` and family are non-blocking functions, at least from userpace point of view. They return either success or failure. They are thread-safe, that's enough to know. Don't think of them in execution blocking/waiting context.

Comment: The heap-allocation/deallocation functions are *thread-safe* (i.e. multiple threads can call them at the same time without causing race conditions), but they aren't *real-time safe*.  So you can't safely call them from e.g. a CoreAudio audio-callback function, because they might take long enough to return that the system's outgoing-audio buffer empties and an audio glitch is produced.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes. The memory allocation functions are required to be thread-safe. C17 paragraph 7.22.3-2 says:

> ... memory allocation functions behave as
> though they accessed only memory locations accessible through their arguments and not other static duration storage ... Calls to these functions that allocate or deallocate a particular region of memory shall occur in a single total order, and each such deallocation call shall synchronize with the next allocation (if any) in this order.

How this is accomplished is up to the library implementation. Thus, it is possible that an implementation may use a mutex to synchronize memory allocation/deallocation between threads and thus cause execution of a thread to potentially wait for the mutex to be free.

It is important to be aware that while the memory allocation functions are required to be *thread-safe*, they are not required to be *re-entrant* (i.e. they cannot be used safely from a signal handler).

Of course, a particular library implementation may provide memory allocation functions with guarantees beyond those required by the Standard.

Answer (score 0):

> If I invoke the same method in parallel in two or more threads, they will make the threads wait (unable to continue execution until the other thread finishes using it), like a mutex?

A mutex only makes threads wait if the mutex is *contested.* If two threads try to lock the same mutex at the same time, *one* of them will win the race, and the winner will *not* wait. Only the loser will have to wait until the winner unlocks the mutex.

The trick is, to avoid contention for mutexes. In a well designed program, where no thread ever keeps a mutex locked for longer than the proverbial "blink of an eye," threads almost never have to wait when they try to lock a mutex.

In any decent heap allocator, `malloc` and `free` and `realloc` will never keep any mutex locked for longer than a "blink of an eye," and threads will rarely ever have to wait when they allocate or free heap objects.